# Postfix version when service stopped

Tags: postfix, version

How can I check the version of `postfix` when the service is stopped and I can't start it now? I can't find files with this information because I can't use `postconf` now.

The server is cloned from another system for analysis purposes, so I can't use the package manager.

Comment: Use your package manager?

Comment: I've clone server without services for analysis. Can i read version from some file?

Comment: Please include OS and Version. It will help contributors as commands may vary from OS to OS

Answer (score 0):

```
strings $( which postfix)| grep 'mail_version='
```